# How do you make the images from your formula field show up in exported report?

Tags: reporting, image-formula

Hi I am trying to make my images from a formula field show up in an exported report.

Here is a sample of the image file Note I do have Externally Available Image checked

[image]

Here is how I see the Excel File when I export

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the same issue. And that was the issue of URL.

Copy the **Image URL(Right click on Image, open it in new tab and copy URL from address bar)** and use it in Formula Field.

```
Formula Field Formula : IMAGE('IMAGE URL','IMAGE Name', Size-X, Size-Y)
```

Comment: I am using the same code but still missing image in report.